# Using pmap to apply different regular expressions to different variables in a tibble?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to apply different regular expressions to different variables in a tibble. For example, I've made a tibble listing 1) the variable name I want to modify, 2) the regex I want to match, and 3) the replacement string. I'd like to apply the regex/replacement to the variable in a different data frame.

So my "configuration" tibble looks like this:

```
test_config <-  dplyr::tibble(
  string_col = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"),
  pattern = c("^\\.$", "^NA$", "^NULL$", "^$"),
  replacement = c("","","", "")
)
```

I'd like to apply this to a target tibble:

```
test_target <- dplyr::tibble(
  col1 = c("Foo", "bar", ".", "NA", "NULL"),
  col2 = c("Foo", "bar", ".", "NA", "NULL"),
  col3 = c("Foo", "bar", ".", "NA", "NULL"),
  col4 = c("NULL", "NA", "Foo", ".", "bar")
)
```

So the goal is to replace a different string with an empty string in each column/variable of the test_target.

The result should be like this:

```
result <- dplyr::tibble(
  col1 = c("Foo", "bar", "", "NA", "NULL"),
  col2 = c("Foo", "bar", ".", "", "NULL"),
  col3 = c("Foo", "bar", ".", "NA", ""),
  col4 = c("NULL", "NA", "Foo", ".", "bar")
)
```

I can do what I want with a for loop, like this:

```
for (i in seq(nrow(test_config))) {
  test_target <- dplyr::mutate_at(test_target,
                   .vars = dplyr::vars(
                     tidyselect::matches(test_config$string_col[[i]])),
                   .funs = dplyr::funs(
                     stringr::str_replace_all(
                       ., test_config$pattern[[i]], 
                       test_config$replacement[[i]]))
  )
}
```

Instead, is there a more tidy way to do what I want?
So far, thinking that `purrr::pmap` was the tool for the job, I've made a function that takes a data frame, variable name, regular expression, and replacement value and returns the data frame with a single variable modified. It behaves as expected:

```
testFun <- function(df, colName, regex, repVal){
  colName <- dplyr::enquo(colName)
  df <- dplyr::mutate_at(df,
                         .vars = dplyr::vars(
                           tidyselect::matches(!!colName)),
                         .funs = dplyr::funs(
                           stringr::str_replace_all(., regex, repVal))
  )
}

# try with example
out <- testFun(test_target, 
               test_config$string_col[[1]], 
               test_config$pattern[[1]], 
               "")
```

However, when I try to use that function with pmap, I run into a couple problems:
1) is there a better way to build the list for the pmap call than this?

```
purrr::pmap(
    list(test_target, 
         test_config$string_col, 
         test_config$pattern, 
         test_config$replacement),
    testFun
)
```

2) When I call pmap, I get an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"
Called from: tbl_vars(tbl)
```

Can any of you suggest a way to use pmap to do what I want, or is there a different or better tidyverse approach to the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I see that my example is insufficient! The target tibble may have variables for which I do not want to apply a regex. So I do need to be able to select the variables in the target using the values in test_config$string_col.

Comment: I've chosen to accept the great solutions to the question as stated, and ask my un-stated case as a different question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071578/using-pmap-with-a-to-apply-different-regular-expressions-to-different-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a function (your function is actually the source of the problem): you can use `str_replace_all` directly.

```
pmap_dfr(
  list(test_target,
       test_config$pattern,
       test_config$replacement),
  str_replace_all
)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  col1  col2  col3  col4 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Foo   Foo   Foo   NULL 
2 bar   bar   bar   NA   
3 ""    .     .     Foo  
4 NA    ""    NA    .    
5 NULL  NULL  ""    bar
```

Comment: This is fairly magical and wonderful, but breaks if my config file doesn't have a regex for a column in the target, or the config file row order is different than the target tibble. So I think I want a mutate_at with column name selection to solve that problem. And thanks for the hint on my function being the problem - I'll look more - I'm certainly not confident about the vars and tidyselect parts...

Comment: OK. Advice for next time: try to make sure to have all the conditions of your problem in your question and reprex

Comment: Yes, sorry - I didn't think of that condition when composing my question! Your solution is very elegant given the question as stated! Thanks!

Comment: You know what, Instead, I think I'll ask a new, different question. Your answer is great!

Comment: OK. I'll look for it and try to see if I can help. Also, detail: but if you want to output a data frame, you want to use `pmap_dfr`: `pmap` will output a list.

Comment: New question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071578/using-pmap-with-a-to-apply-different-regular-expressions-to-different-variables - thanks. And check to the `pmap_dfr` - thx.

Comment: `pmap_dfr` and `pmap_dfc` will apply `bind_rows` and `bind_cols` under the hood

Answer (score 2):

Another method using `map2_dfc` (the `_dfc` suffix is also available for `pmap`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map2_dfc(test_target, seq_along(test_target), 
         ~sub(test_config$pattern[.y], 
              test_config$replacement[.y], .x))
```

or `imap_dfc` (note that with this, you lose the column names):

```
imap_dfc(unname(test_target), 
         ~sub(test_config$pattern[.y], 
              test_config$replacement[.y], .x))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  col1  col2  col3  col4 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Foo   Foo   Foo   NULL 
2 bar   bar   bar   NA   
3 ""    .     .     Foo  
4 NA    ""    NA    .    
5 NULL  NULL  ""    bar
```

Comment: Sorry, @avid_useR - my question was incomplete! Your solution is elegant, but I left a condition out, that breaks it - my config file may not have a regex for every column in the target, or the config file row order may differ from the target tibble. So I think I need something like a mutate_at for column name selection to solve that problem. Sorry for my omission! I've added a comment to my question.

Comment: You know what, Instead, I think I'll ask a new, different question!